# Google Drive close automatically after authentication

Tags: google-picker

I am working on Google Drive picker in my web application. Everything works fine but when it opens an Authentication window and I approved it, the window automatically close without showing or allowing file selection.

Here is my JavaScript code:

> // The Browser API key obtained from the Google API Console.
>       var developerKey = '*****************************';

```
// The Client ID obtained from the Google API Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
var clientId = '*********-k826p6sl1qkhpnrtbbi0jktboijupvf9.apps.googleusercontent.com';

// Scope to use to access user's photos.
var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly';

var pickerApiLoaded = false;
var oauthToken;

// Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.load('auth2', onAuthApiLoad);
    gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
}

function onAuthApiLoad() {
    var authBtn = document.getElementById('GoogleDrive');
    authBtn.disabled = false;
    authBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        gapi.auth2.authorize({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: scope
        }, handleAuthResult);
    });
}

function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
    }
}

// Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
function createPicker() {

    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }

}

// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

I am using below reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide your error log?