# Google Drive Picker apiv3 closes upon authorization

Tags: firefox, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-shared-drive

I am unable to login to my google drive picker api via firefox. It does work fine in chrome.

I am seeing:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

So I then tried to allow everything for testing and I still am unable to load the drive picker via Firefox 60 on OSX.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
```

I did add the apps domain to the approved list. I am not quite sure how to debug this as it appears to be handed off to Google at this point when it is going through the authentication process.

I see in the console it goes to here and then stops:

```
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/3723580519-idpiframe.js
```

I believe it is similar issue to what is going on here. I am using close to the same default example code from Google.
[Google Drive close automatically after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734865/google-drive-close-automatically-after-authentication)

I noticed in chrome now I see in https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/3723580519-idpiframe.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: (b || "").split is not a function
```

It appears there maybe an issue here but I have not seen any updates:
https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/409

Comment: It appears to work now, but I am not sure why? I installed firefox nightly and that works but then the firefox 60 works, so I am thinking it maybe a caching issue or login issue somehow?

Comment: I tested on a second machine and installing Firefox nightly seems to fix the issue with firefox 60... so it appears to be something with Firefox. It's fixed now.